# Whether to use ArcGIS Platform (from Esri) or Google Maps API for large number of polygons?

Tags: google-maps-api, arcgis-platform

I am in the planning phases of building a web based application which will be served on IOS devices through a custom application with HTML container. The functionality will be to display a number of icon markers as well as polygons. The core functionality is fairly simple which is to render markers and polygons.

The issue I am having is with a feature which I have agreed to which is dynamically adding and removing polygons. I can certainly do this with client side on google maps. However performance of polygons on client side is very poor. There is also a limit of ~10 KML files at any one time to be added to a google map. The polygons need to be in separate KML files so that I can add and remove them.

My question is does ESRI GIS maps handle large amounts of polygons being added/removed better than google maps apiv3?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't use GeoServer?

Comment: No real reason. I have the most experience with google maps which is why that was the first api I had chosen. Does GeoServer provide better handling of large number of markers and polygons?

Comment: geoserver can restrict or generalise the data on the fly - increasing the user-sides performance.

Comment: Are there any tutorials on GeoServer? I cannot seem to find any. This is new technology to me.